# Symfony - decimal number in integer type field causes no validation error

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

This is the field in Entity:

```
/**
* @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"group1"})
* @Assert\Type(type="integer", groups={"group1"})
* @Assert\Range(min=0, groups={"group1"})
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $cableCount;
```

and this is the corresponding field in the form type:

```
$builder->add('cableCount', IntegerType::class, [
     'label' => 'Cable Count',
     'required' => true
]);
```

The field is rendered with up and down arrows and user can increase and decrease the values like 1, 2, 3, ...
However user can also type in 3.45 and submit the form. No validation error pops up. just the value is rounded to 3. the expected behavior is to get a validation error informing the user that this field can accept only integer numbers.

How should I solve this issue?
is there a built-in feature in symfony for this or should I create a custom constraint?

Comment: Updated my answer with Twig overriding the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symfony's **[IntegerType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html)** will [automatically round](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html#rounding-mode) whatever number you send to it.  On the browser side, if you use **IntegerType** then it will normally check for a valid integer before letting you submit the form.

In order to get what you want, you should use a **[NumberType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html)**.  Your `@Assert\Type(type="integer", groups={"group1"})` will then be ran on the server and appropriately error if you submit a non-integer.

The only issue there is you lose the up/down arrows.  If you want that you'll have to override with a custom form theme for the **NumberType**.  Something like this:

```
{%- block number_widget -%}
    {%- set type = form.vars.attr['int'] is defined and form.vars.attr['int']
        ? 'number'
        : type|default('text')
    -%}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{%- endblock number_widget -%}
```

Then in your form type, specify that `attr` like so:

```
$builder->add('cableCount', NumberType::class, [
    'label' => 'Cable Count',
    'required' => true,
    'attr' => [
        'int' => true,
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. that solved the issue. I think you forgot to change IntegerType to NumberType in FormType.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Regex assert like this:

```
/** @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\d*$/") */
```

Edit: As mentionned by @JasonRoman, you first have to deal with the [IntegerType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html) who will automatically round your inputs.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue when using the `IntegerType` class

Comment: Yes I just saw on [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html) that your input will always be rounded. Maybe you could try to play with the `scale` and `rounding_mode` fields options to allow decimals and then let the validator throw an error.